# Number of positive eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does number of positive eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ will be equal to number of positive eigenvalues of $(Q^t)AQ$, where $Q$ is some $n\times n$ invertible matrix and $A$ is also $n\times n$ matrix.$Q^t$ represents transpose of $Q$.

Comment: I suspect not. Have you tried it with some "random" matrices? Or do you have a reason to think so (for example, it is a problem from a book)?

Comment: @daw But here A is not a Symmetric matrix!

Comment: It's not true. Try some examples. (Some software recommended).

Comment: Try with $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: @ajotatxe  ok I am trying

Comment: Not in general, but if $Q^{-1}=Q^t$ then $(Q^t)AQ$ and $A$ have the same characteristic polynomial and hence the same eigenvalues.